# Search by using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Am trying to search the student details with their name or email or mobile. For this I've three textboxes for Name, Email and Mobile.

And in my code I tried to get these details like,

```
DataObject entities=new DataObject();

foreach (DataObject.Student student in entities.students.Where(p => 
          (p.FIRSTNAME+p.LASTNAME).Contains(txtName.Text)
          || p.MOBILE.Contains(txtMobile.Text)
          || p.EMAIL.Contains(txtEmail.Text))
        {
            //
        }
```

and here, if I type `sham` in the Email or in the Name textbox, its listing all the student details available in the database instead of listing only the student name or email contains `sham`.

When I was debugging this, I tried giving the same value`sham,sham,sham` for name,mobile and email its listing perfectly, and also if I want to search by name that contains `sham`, and If I type `sham` in name, and anything else in the email and mobile, this also working perfectly....

One thing I came to know from this is, it expects all the parameter should have some value, I dunno why this expects like this, and I dunno how to fix this, can anyone help me here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Put more code in your question. The problem may be elsewhere.

Comment: am simply using this code only

Comment: do the other students have a empty Mobile or Email ? the problem cud be, if u'r not typing an email-adderss, it pick's all students up without entered email

Comment: thanks davee, for ur response, I got the solution, here Mobile and Email are mandatory fields, so these two are not empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, that every string "contains" an empty string, so if some of the textboxes are empty, some of the "OR" conditions will return `true` for every student name and you get all students. Try to change the query to:

```
foreach (DataObject.Student student in entities.students.Where(p => 
         ((txtName.Text != string.Empty)
             ? (p.FIRSTNAME+p.LASTNAME).Contains(txtName.Text)
             : false)
      || ((txtMobile.Text != string.Empty)
             ? p.MOBILE.Contains(txtMobile.Text)
             : false)
      || ((txtEmail.Text != string.Empty)
             ? p.EMAIL.Contains(txtEmail.Text)
             : false))
{
    //
}
```

Instead of `XXX.Text != string.Empty` you can also try `string.IsNullOrEmpty(XXX.Text)` to catch the `null` case as well. But I am not sure if LINQ to Entities will accept this method.

**Edit**

`string.IsNullOrEmpty(XXX.Text)` works with LINQ to Entities, I've found a query in my own code that uses it without problems, so the better solution to check for empty string and for `null` is:

```
foreach (DataObject.Student student in entities.students.Where(p => 
         (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text)
             ? (p.FIRSTNAME+p.LASTNAME).Contains(txtName.Text)
             : false)
      || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMobile.Text)
             ? p.MOBILE.Contains(txtMobile.Text)
             : false)
      || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmail.Text)
             ? p.EMAIL.Contains(txtEmail.Text)
             : false))
{
    //
}
```